# How to set humanized name of padrino module?

Tags: padrino

How are you.
I have just installed padrino framework admin panel.
And it shows several tabs in admin module.
I want to rename the labels. but how to do it?
This is view side code

```
<%= link_to project_module.human_name, url(project_module.path) %>
```

Here I can't set human_name of project_module.
And this is module definition in application.rb

```
access_control.roles_for :admin do |role|
      role.project_module :accounts, '/accounts'
      role.project_module :venues, '/venues'
      role.project_module :shows, '/shows'
end
```

Now tabs labels are Accounts, Venues, Shows.
how to set them as  Users, MyVenues, MyShows?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just seemed to hit this issue tonight as well.  It seems that this is a slight bug that is in the core Padrino framework.

The standard navigation logic out of the box will never produce a proper localized text.  It renders the output of function .humanize

https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/8bd3796d45eae5e3f7dc52316c8c25c44563f8cd/padrino-admin/lib/padrino-admin/access_control.rb#L176

At best, the humanize function will upcase your text.  See https://apidock.com/rails/String/humanize

You can replace the human_name reference with the I18n.t() localizable function:

```
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav.pull-left
        - project_modules.each do |project_module|
          %li{:class => "navbar-module #{('active' if request.path_info =~ /^#{project_module.path}/)}"}
            =link_to I18n.t(project_module.name), url(project_module.path)
```

See http://padrinorb.com/guides/features/localization/ for reference.

One note, the navigation is not model aware, so your translated text will need to be right under the locale reference in the yml file.

Ex.

```
en:
  accounts: Users
  venues: MyVenue
  shows: MyShows
```

This should do the trick.  Let me know if you have any questions.